# How to trim/substr from varchar when decimal place found in oracle?

Tags: sql, string, oracle, substr

**How to trim after decimal(.) from varchar2 in oracle?**

 Example 1: '2999.89' should be return '2999'

 Example 1: 'V59.00' should be return 'V59'

Comment: select id, trunc(varchar2, 0 ) from table where rownum < 10;
<br> In above case it is not working only in case of  "select trunc('299.89', 0) from dual" working;

Comment: Use **substr** and **instr** since they are characters and not numbers.

Answer (score 2):

You could use **SUBSTR** and **INSTR**.

```
For example,

SQL> WITH DATA(str) AS(
  2  SELECT '2999.89' FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 'V59.00' FROM dual
  4  )
  5  SELECT str, SUBSTR(str, 1, instr(str, '.', 1, 1)-1) new_str FROM DATA;

STR     NEW_STR
------- -------
2999.89 2999
V59.00  V59

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`instr`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions068.htm) to find the index of `.` and then [`substr`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions162.htm) to return the string up to that position:

```
SELECT SUBSTR (col, 1, INSTR(col, '.') - 1)
FROM   mytable
```

Comment: The index for `substr` starts from `1` and not `0`. Though it would work, but it is a bad practice.

Comment: `substr` explicitly treats index 0 as 1, but you're probably right, it's a bad habit to use it in Oracle. I'll amend my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH DATA(str) AS(
    SELECT '2999.89' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'V59.00' FROM dual
)
SELECT str, REGEXP_SUBSTR(str,'^([^.]*)',1) new_str FROM DATA;
```